# ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation and __doPostBack()

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, dopostback

I'm trying to register some buttons for event registration because I keep getting the "Invalid postback or callback argument". Since I'm passing the buttons' events manually through __doPostBacks(), due to client-side validation, I think it has something to do with that.

I overrode Render to use RegisterForEventValidation like this:

```
protected override void  Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(btnNuevo.UniqueID);
    ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(btnBorrar.UniqueID);
    ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(btnEditar.UniqueID);
    ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(btnAlquilar.UniqueID); 
    base.Render(writer);
}
```

But the __doPostBacks on the client-side .aspx page are written like this:

```
...
__doPostBack('<%= btnNuevo.UniqueID %>', "");
...
__doPostBack('<%= btnBorrar.UniqueID %>', selected.childNodes[0].innerText);
...
__doPostBack('<%= btnEditar.UniqueID %>', index);
...
__doPostBack('<%= btnAlquilar.UniqueID %>', indexaux);
```

where selected.childNodes[0].innerText, index and indexaux are strings. This still throws that Exception.

I know there's an overload of RegisterForEventValidation where you pass it a key for the control, and the arguments.

The thing is, I don't know how to write that. I'm not suppossed to know fore-hand what the argument is going to be, since selecter, index and indexaux depend on the user interaction with the page (namely, selecting a row in a GridView). The only examples I find are those where the argument is always the same, so they just write  RegisterForEventValidation("nameOfControl", "XXXX"), where "XXXX" is a fixed string.

Any ideas regarding how to write this, or if this isn't the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to call `__doPostBack` manually at all for client-side validation. Maybe it's easier to ask how to use ASP.NET validators with your clintside validation. Apart from that i don't understand why calling `__doPostBack` should throw _"Invalid postback or callback argument_. The source of this error is somewhere else. You're changing not the buttons on clientside but other controls, hence you need to register these and their valid values(that ASP.NET does not know).

Comment: The situation is like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10126274/calling-a-code-behind-function-from-javascript-that-may-return-another-javascrip. I figured that the problem lied on the buttons setting on the events having to call a Javascript function first, then a C# function, and the Page not knowing or not recognizing that. That, or a problem with HOW the GridView is changed (because the button that appends a new register on it works fine, but the one that edits a register, by calling the same ModalPopup and doing practically the same, throws the Invalid Postback exception).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're set on this approach, but you could just set `EnableEventValidation` to false in the page directive:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" EnableEventValidation="false" ... %>
```

Comment: I assume that this is what OP actually want to avoid, otherwise he would have asked how to prevent the error and not how to use `RegisterForEventValidation` correctly.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: You might be right. I just figured I would present it as an option, incase OP was not aware that it could be turned off.

Comment: No, Tim Schmelter is right: I'm trying to avoid disabling the Page's EventValidator.